# Windows 10 - Sign into multiple accounts on startup

Tags: windows-10, login

First, let me apologize if this is the wrong place for a question like this. I've been meaning to get a SE account for awhile, and this is my first question.

I have several user accounts on my PC that I need to be logged into to sync some files for cloud storage properly with my administrator account and the internet. Basically, the cloud won't update unless I log into the associated user account (as long as it's signed in, the application will sync automatically).

What I'm trying to find out is if there's a way, on startup, to log into all accounts. Namely, when I open the start menu, I want to see "signed in" on every account. I feel like this is something I should be able to automate. None of the accounts have passwords. Can you recommend software or regedit tweaks I can use to make this happen?

Please let me know if my question is too vague!

Comment: i guess something like [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is a better place to ask such a question...

Comment: Oh, thank you! Again, I wasn't sure. Is there a way to move it, or should I mark this as answered and repost it over there?

Comment: On the whole, I think that it might be better asked here. SuperUser is fine, if your o/s can do it - which I doubt. Ask her for application to help. In this case, a macro recorder might help. Or AutoIt, if the OP can code

Answer (score 1):

There's a new software GoLogin, which allows to manage multiple accounts at the same time https://gologinapp.com

You can try 10 day free trial https://releases-gologin.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/GoLogin-win-latest.exe